# How to draw a semi oval shape with Android vector graphics

Tags: android, geometry, oval

I was trying to make a semi oval shape. I did it but it's reverse. I want to make a oval shape like this image.

[image: top half of a blue ellipse]

I tried this code

```
<vector 

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="10dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">

    <path
        android:pathData="M0 -5.4a13 7 0 1 0 24 0V24H0z"
        android:fillColor="@color/white"/>

</vector>
```

I collected this code from stackverflow. But there is a vector and i am not able to understand it completely.

Comment: The image you provided is the top half of a blue ellipse. What is the image you actually want? Is what you want the top half of a blue ellipse and you are getting something else or what?

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
 <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0">

<path
    android:name="circle"
    android:fillColor="#fff"
    android:pathData="M12,38m-10,0a10,10 0,1 1,20 0a10,10 0,1 1,-20 0" />

</vector>
```